# No lights in kitchen

Tags: kitchens

Can anyone help me?? Monday.. My lights stop working in my kitchen, laundry room and garage. The outlets work. I tried the breaker and gfci outlets but still no lights in those rooms.

Comment: The breakers for lights and outlets are different, check all the breakers, the lights are not on GFCI breakers

Answer (score 2):

If rechecking the breakers doesn't help (you did turn each one fully off and then back to on, right?), and you can't find another breaker or fuse box, someone needs to start tracing the wiring looking for what isn't connected that should be.

That involves opening up junction boxes and lamp fixtures and switch boxes and testing voltage or continuity... or, easier but requiring specialized equipment, putting a high frequency tone onto the wire and using a receiver to trace the wiring back until you find the place where it should be connected but isn't.

If you aren't already familiar with working on house wiring, this is a job I'd suggest hiring a pro for. It may be anything from a bad connection to a failed breaker to you-name-it. Could even be a failure on just one phase, if you have American-style center-neutral 120/240 coming into the house.

(I used a tone tracer to find the place where a contractor had damaged my wiring, after their electrician declined to believe it was their fault. Unfortunately I borrowed that widget from a friend, and I can no longer tell you much more about it. If one of the the pros here can tell us what it's officially called, I'd really like to see if I can buy one at a reasonable price! I've successfully used a breaker identifier to trace wiring, but those require that the circuit be live to power the transmitter rather than being able to work with power either on or off, and aren't as easy to work with since this is outside their design envelope. And I need to trace some low-voltage wires some time soon.)

[Found the device I used: Greenlee 2007/2008. I really should get one; among other things its low-voltage mode would be a good way to find breaks in audio and data cables.]

Comment: I have been eyeing the Walabot DIY 2 scanner. It's pretty impressive.

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes to reset a breaker you must flip it all the way to the "off" position and then back to the "on" position. They can appear to be in the "on" position but they really aren't.

If they go out again you need someone to trouble shoot it for you because your breaker might need to be replaced.

Comment: While a persistently-tripping breaker may be defective, repeated tripping is more likely caused by a downstream wiring fault.